# Adding list item using jQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had a simple to-do list app that worked fine, recently I overhauled the app using Bootstrap, before I wasnt using any css framework. Now the jQuery is not working properly... Why is this?

Here is the relevent HTML:

```
<div id="to-do">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id ="input" placeholder ="I need to...">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id ="add" type="submit">Add Item</button>

    </form>

    <ul id="list"></ul>

</div>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
$(function() {

// configuration

// button
var add = $('#add');

// list container
var listContainer = $('#list');



// click event for button

add.on('click', function() {


    // value of input
    inputValue = $('#input').val();

    // add new list item
    listContainer.prepend('<li> ' + inputValue + '</li>');
    // clear value input
    $('#input').val('');



});
```

});

Comment: You should incorporate all your html dependencies and body at least.

Comment: Why are you using `form` and `type="submit"`?

Comment: I think it because it come from a part of the style of this bloc in Bootstrap design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine works fine, does is what you needed to do ?

```js
$(function() {
  

// configuration

// button
var add = $('#add');

// list container
var listContainer = $('#list');



// click event for button

add.on('click', function() {

     event.preventDefault(); // stop default behaviour of submit button
    // value of input
    inputValue = $('#input').val();

    // add new list item
    listContainer.prepend('<li> ' + inputValue + '</li>');
    // clear value input
    $('#input').val('');



});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="to-do">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id ="input" placeholder ="I need to...">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id ="add" type="submit">Add Item</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="list"></ul>

</div>
```

Comment: event.preventDefault(); - This fixed it thanks, why did I have to use that?

Comment: @MarkShakespeare event.preventDefault(). prevent the default nature of event, so here submit